# Angular Observable wait till it is finished

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, http, observable

I have written a small angular application where I am getting data from a rest api. For this purpose I'm using observables. My problem is now, that they are asynchron.

```
let tempArray: boolean[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    this._myservice.checkData(data[i]).subscribe(
        result => {
            tempArray.push(result);
            console.log('Before');
            console.log(tempArray);
        },
            error => console.log(error),
    );
}
console.log('After');
console.log(tempArray);
```

My problem is now, that the result data not in the destined array after the subscription, as you see in the picture below. How can I solve this, without writing the whole code into the subscription?

[image]

Comment: Why you need that ? It is the best approached to handle any code related with the Observable produced values inside of the subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forkJoin` operator. It's like `Promise.all` but for observables.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';

forkJoin(
  this._myservice.checkData(data[0]),
  this._myservice.checkData(data[1]),
  this._myservice.checkData(data[2])
).subscribe(result => {
  // result[0] is the first result
  // result[1] is the second result
  // result[2] is the third result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use `async/await`, which, basically, does put all the code inside a subscription, only it does it under the hood:

```
let tempArray: boolean[] = [];
const promises = Promise<bool>[];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    promises.push(this._myservice.checkData(data[i]).toPromise());
}

// now, we create a promise that groups the previous ones, and await for it:

try {
    tempArray = await Promise.all(promises);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}

console.log('After');
console.log(tempArray);
```

As you see, `async/await` works with promises, not observables, but it's easy to turn ones into the others- You just need to make sure that `toPromise` from `RxJS` is imported.

You can read more about `async/await` here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html